# Invalid query : URI parse exception in Apache HTTP Client used in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-httpclient-4.x, yahoo-api

I'm trying to invoke a Yahoo API using a Apache Camel.

The Yahoo API is 
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20music.artist.search%20where%20keyword%3D%22Madonna%22&format=json

My route looks like this.

```
    from("direct:start_yahoo_artist")
            .process(new HTTPRequestParamProcessor())
            .setHeader(
                    Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,
                    simple("select+*+from+music.artist.search+where+keyword%3D%{in.headers.artist}%22&format=json"))
                    //simple("select * from music.artist.search where keyword=\"{in.headers.artist}\"&format=json"))
            .to("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql")
            .unmarshal()
            .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, YahooMusicArtistResponseObject.class)
            /*.bean(EmbeddedDroolsRuleEngine.class, "callRuleEngine")*/
            .process(new Processor() {

                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody());

                }
            });
```

However, I'm getting an Invalid query exception. What is the correct way of encoding the URI?

```
[               qtp263093125-29] Tracer                         INFO  ID-server190-tm-rtsslab-64570-1345237236639-0-2 >>> (route6)  --> http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql <<< Pattern:InOut, Headers:{CamelHttpMethod=GET, artist=Madonna, breadcrumbId=ID-server190-tm-rtsslab-64570-1345237236639-0-1, CamelHttpQuery=select+*+from+music.artist.search+where+keyword%3D%{in.headers.artist}%22&format=json}, BodyType:null, Body:[Body is null]
[               qtp263093125-29] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-server190-tm-rtsslab-64570-1345237236639-0-3 on ExchangeId: ID-server190-tm-rtsslab-64570-1345237236639-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: Invalid query
org.apache.commons.httpclient.URIException: Invalid query
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.parseUriReference(URI.java:2049)[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI.<init>(URI.java:147)[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getURI(HttpMethodBase.java:265)[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:383)[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.executeMethod(HttpProducer.java:243)[camel-http-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this part:

```
+keyword%3D%{in.headers.artist}%22
```

the normal way to inline variables in simple is `${in.headers.artist}` not `%{in.headers.artist}` but you might have configured this to `{ } ?`

But you do not have quotation marks before the artist string, only after - which is different to your working URL above.

Shouldn't this part of the url be: `+keyword%3D%22${in.headers.artist}%22  (+keyword="madonna")` ?